# LINQ file upload malfunction w EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am refactoring a section of my app to save a file to the Db in a bit field. In other places I have used the SqlCommand method but here I would like to latch on to my existing EF procedure, for many reasons not apparent. The uploader works fine but it breaks down when it gets to the LINQ. When I query the Db, instead of the usual "0x25504462D..." in the bit field, I get simply "0x". Attempting to view the file gets a message "file is empty". Am I close? The other fields are inserted perfectly, and there are no errors in the insert process. How do I "feed" the file to the fileUpload? Please advise.

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[inputTagName];
FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload(); 

using (DBEntities ode = new DBEntities())
{
    (check if file exists...)
    else
    {  
        MyModels.File newfile = new MyModels.File();
        newfile.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        newfile.Name = fn;
        newfile.VirtualPath = filePath;
        newfile.DateTimeUploaded = DateTime.Now;
        newfile.binFile = fileUpload.FileBytes;
        ode.AddToFiles(newfile);
    }
    ode.SaveChanges();
}
```

[image]

Comment: What type is the binFile property declared to as?

Comment: @denchu - when I set up the column I chose "bit", when I look at the table design, it shows the column as "varbinary(max)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much lamenting and gnashing of teeth (and encouragement from @denchu) it was apparent I needed to read the data:

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[inputTagName];
 //var uploadedFile = new byte[file.InputStream.Length];
 BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
 byte[] uploadedFile = br.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);

   using (DBEntities ode = new DBEntities())
   {
      (check if file exists...)

   else
   {  
        MyModels.File newfile = new MyModels.File();
        newfile.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        newfile.Name = fn;
        newfile.VirtualPath = filePath;
        newfile.DateTimeUploaded = DateTime.Now;
        newfile.binFile = uploadedFile;
        ode.AddToFiles(newfile);
  }

   ode.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try getting the `byte[]' value of the uploaded file.

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[inputTagName];
var uploadedFile = new byte[file.InputStream.Length];

using (DBEntities ode = new DBEntities())
{
    (check if file exists...)

    else
    {  
            MyModels.File newfile = new MyModels.File();
            newfile.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            newfile.Name = fn;
            newfile.VirtualPath = filePath;
            newfile.DateTimeUploaded = DateTime.Now;
            newfile.binFile = uploadedFile;
            ode.AddToFiles(newfile);
    }

    ode.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I used varbinary in SQL when declaring the property, and as byte[] in the Model.

Comment: this inserts "0x000000000000000000000000000..." into the Db. Could you please explain a little more about "I used varbinary in SQL"? It is an existing table with over 2000 records in it.

Comment: If you add a breakpoint and check the current value of `file`, what is the actual value of it?

Comment: added breakpoint at "MyModels.File newfile = new MyModels.File();". Edited question to display "file" properties

Comment: @Darkloki did you check what value is getting passed to `uploadedFile`?

Comment: Thanx for sticking with me on this, the value of uploadedFile is {byte[5314063]}. When I went to expand it I got a warning the it contained more than 100,000 children and could only display that many (FYI). The value of each child is "0" and the type is byte